# Should I initiate a Session with Session.set('key', undefined)?

Tags: meteor

I new to Meteor and I've found myself initiating a Session with:

```
Session.set('key', undefined);
```

Then somewhere inside a helper, say, I'd set it:

```
...
Session.set('key, some value);
...
```

I'm not sure why I've started doing this; I may have seen it done somewhere and have just copied it. Can I just set the Session when I need it to hold the unique value and forget the initial 'undefined' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're 100% sure this `Session` should be initialized, Meteor has special method for this:

```
Session.setDefault(key, value);
```

[Reference for `Session.setDefault`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_set_default)

Comment: Thanks. I guess in my situations most of the time, it really doesn't need to be initialized. Almost all of my Sessions are being set by a button click in an event map. I had seen the setDefault method earlier too, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary.